# How to split the background-color in 4

Tags: html, css

I have this div:

```
<div data-role="page" id="menupage"></div>
```

That represents the body of a page. And I want to make it's background in 4 colors. I know how to make it in 2:

```
#menupage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right, 
    #FFF 0%, 
    #FFF 50%, 
    #008DD2 50%, 
    #008DD2 100%
  );
}
```

I want to have something like this:
[image]

**PS**: if you like the colors:

```
orange: #F26522;
green:  #BBC274;
```

Can somebody help? Thank you!

Comment: I have created this using two divs who making background and one div for data, have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/fxekbr8e/.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With CSS3, you can apply  [`multiple backgrounds`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds).

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menupage{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FFF 0%, #FFF 50%, #008DD2 50%, #008DD2 100%), linear-gradient(to right, #F2651C 0%, #F2651C 50%, #BCC375 50%, #BCC375 100%);
  background-size: 100% 50%;
  background-position: center top, center bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div data-role="page" id="menupage"></div>
```

Comment: @Dejan Munjiza Thanks, i really appreciate it.